# majority vote TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to map sub categories to a 'majority' parent category. Looking at this example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID INT,
    SubCategory NVARCHAR(100),
    Category NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT 1, N'SC1', N'C1'
        UNION 
    SELECT 2, N'SC1', N'C1'
        UNION 
    SELECT 3, N'SC1', N'C1'
        UNION 
    SELECT 4, N'SC1', N'C2'
        UNION 
    SELECT 5, N'SC1', N'C2'
```

sub category SC1 can belong to 2 'parent' categories: C1, C2 but C1 is assigned more to SC1 than C2 so it represents the majority. I am currently using a correlated sub query to map sun categories to their majority parent categroy like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID INT,
    SubCategory NVARCHAR(100),
    Category NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT 1, N'SC1', N'C1'
        UNION 
    SELECT 2, N'SC1', N'C1'
        UNION 
    SELECT 3, N'SC1', N'C1'
        UNION 
    SELECT 4, N'SC1', N'C2'
        UNION 
    SELECT 5, N'SC1', N'C2'

SELECT 
    Id, 
    OuterQuery.SubCategory,
    Category = (SELECT TOP 1 Category FROM #Temp AS InnerQuery   
                WHERE InnerQuery.SubCategory = OuterQuery.SubCategory  
                GROUP BY InnerQuery.SubCategory, InnerQuery.Category                    
                ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Id) DESC)
FROM #Temp AS OuterQuery
```

Is this a correct way of achieving want I want to?

Comment: What should happen if two (or more) categories have equally high counts for a subcategory? Should two (or more) rows be returned by the query? Or is there some form of tie-breaking rule? Or something else?

Comment: In knew someone would ask (-:. In this, in my case very unlikely scenario, I would just take the first (TOP 1).

Comment: Why can a subcategory be in the same category more than once? Is this an analogy for something else?

Comment: Data errors. I have to find the 'best' common denominator.

Comment: That returns 5 rows.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes, It mapped all SC1s to the majority parent category C1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    ID INT,
    SubCategory NVARCHAR(100),
    Category NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @t
    VALUES
    ( 1, N'SC1', N'C1'),
    (2, N'SC1', N'C1'),
    (3, N'SC1', N'C1'),
    (4, N'SC1', N'C2'),
    (5, N'SC1', N'C2'),
    (6, N'SC2', N'C2'),
    (7, N'SC2', N'C2'),
    (8, N'SC2', N'C3');

WITH a AS (
    SELECT 
        subcategory, 
        category, 
        COUNT(id) cnt 
    FROM @t 
    GROUP BY 
        SubCategory, 
        category
), b as (
    SELECT 
        subcategory, 
        category,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER   
            (PARTITION BY subcategory ORDER BY cnt DESC) row 
    FROM a
)
SELECT 
    subcategory, 
    category AS Majority 
FROM b 
WHERE row = 1
```

This produces the result:

```
subcategory Majority 
SC1 C1
SC2 C2
```

Comment: yeah that's something I would also have tried. do you think PARTITION BY would be better performing and/or is my approach fundamentally wrong?

Comment: It depends on the size of your table I guess. If it's only 5 records I guess they would be about the same but if you have thousands of rows you would do one select top 1 in the inner query for every  row in the outer query. Compare the actual execution plans when you run them both and you'll see how they work with your data.

Comment: Are you missing a where row = 1?

Comment: @Paparazzi: No, you have to scroll down.

Answer (score 1):

There's this way with just subqueries;

Test Data (I've increased the range for this)

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(ID INT, SubCategory NVARCHAR(100), Category NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Temp (ID, SubCategory, Category)
VALUES
(1, N'SC1', N'C1')
,(2, N'SC1', N'C1')
,(3, N'SC1', N'C1')
,(4, N'SC1', N'C2')
,(5, N'SC1', N'C2')
,(6, N'SC2', N'C3')
,(7, N'SC2', N'C3')
,(8, N'SC2', N'C2')
,(9, N'SC2', N'C2')
,(10, N'SC2', N'C2')
,(11, N'SC2', N'C2')
```

Now the query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t.SubCategory
,t.Category
FROM #Temp t

JOIN
(
    SELECT
    SubCategory
    ,Category
    ,COUNT(SubCategory) Ct
    FROM #Temp
    GROUP BY SubCategory, Category
    ) Cont
ON t.SubCategory = cont.SubCategory
AND t.Category = cont.Category

JOIN
(
    SELECT
    a.SubCategory
    ,MAX(a.Ct) MaxCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        SubCategory
        ,Category
        ,COUNT(SubCategory) Ct
        FROM #Temp
        GROUP BY SubCategory, Category
    ) a
    GROUP BY a.SubCategory
) maxi ON t.SubCategory = maxi.SubCategory
AND cont.Ct = maxi.MaxCount
```